# Android studio "hidpi=true" not works

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kde-plasma, hidpi

After upgrading to Android Studio 4.0.1 Build #AI-193.6911.18.40.6626763 from 3.6.1 IDE's scale factor become incorrect (all UI elements become small). Appending "hidpi=true" in idea.properties has no effect.
Adding "-Dsun.java2d.uiScale=2 -Dswing.defaultlaf=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel \ -Didea.jre.check=true -Dhidpi=true" to launch options in studio.sh file is results to same: no effect. Maybe, there are some another way to force scale factor? My distribution is KDE Neon

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and solved it by **installing the preview version** of the upcoming release, Android Studio 4.2 RC 1

https://developer.android.com/studio/preview